# Creating a relative symbolic link through the os package

Tags: go, symlink

I would like to create a relative symbolic link in go using the os package.

os already [contains the function: `os.SymLink(oldname, newname string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Symlink), but it cannot create relative symlinks.

For example, if I run the following:

```
package main 

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    path := "/tmp/rolfl/symexample"
    target := filepath.Join(path, "symtarget.txt")
    os.MkdirAll(path, 0755)
    ioutil.WriteFile(target, []byte("Hello\n"), 0644)
    symlink := filepath.Join(path, "symlink")
    os.Symlink(target, symlink)
}
```

it creates the following in my filesystem:

```
$ ls -la /tmp/rolfl/symexample
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 rolf rolf 4096 Feb 21 15:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 rolf rolf 4096 Feb 21 15:21 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rolf rolf   35 Feb 21 15:21 symlink -> /tmp/rolfl/symexample/symtarget.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 rolf rolf    6 Feb 21 15:21 symtarget.txt
```

How can I use golang to create the relative symlink that looks like:

```
$ ln -s symtarget.txt symrelative
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 rolf rolf 4096 Feb 21 15:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 rolf rolf 4096 Feb 21 15:21 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rolf rolf   35 Feb 21 15:21 symlink -> /tmp/rolfl/symexample/symtarget.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rolf rolf   13 Feb 21 15:23 symrelative -> symtarget.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 rolf rolf    6 Feb 21 15:21 symtarget.txt
```

I want something that's like the `symrelative` above.

Do I have to resort to `os/exec`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("ln", "-s", "symtarget.txt", "symlink")
cmd.Dir = "/tmp/rolfl/symexample"
cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't include the absolute path to `symtarget.txt` when calling [`os.Symlink`](https://godoc.org/os#Symlink); only use it when writing to the file:

```
package main 

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    path := "/tmp/rolfl/symexample"
    target := "symtarget.txt"
    os.MkdirAll(path, 0755)
    ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(path, "symtarget.txt"), []byte("Hello\n"), 0644)
    symlink := filepath.Join(path, "symlink")
    os.Symlink(target, symlink)
}
```

Comment: How come this is an answer?? It doesn't create relative symlink at all. Just to reming: relative symlink could look like: `a.txt -> ../../something/a.txt`

Comment: @user64204 
`os.Symlink("../../something/a.txt", "/tmp/foo/bar/a.txt")`

Comment: @AlexanderYastrebov "/tmp/foo/bar/a.txt" is an absolute path.

Comment: @user64204
Yes, this snippet will create symlink `a.txt` in the `/tmp/foo/bar/` directory that points to the `../../something/a.txt`

<br>

~$ ls -og /tmp/foo/bar/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 21 Mär 25 19:15 a.txt -> ../../something/a.txt